# Как сделать поиск по ключевому слову с занесением в переменную?

Tags: python

Дан текстовый файл с данными в виде:

```
123:4000
567:3000
890:2000
```

Необходимо выполнить поиск заданного числа (прим. 567) и занести в переменную число в этой строке после двоеточия (т.е. 3000).

Answer (score 2):

например, так:

```
with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
    data = [list(map(int, line[:-1].split(":"))) for line in file.readlines()]

res = [obj[1] for obj in data if obj[0] == 567]
```

Comment: Плюсик за короткость :)

Comment: Благодарю за помощь, ваше решение подошло мне более всего.

Answer (score 2):

```
def search(file, what):
    for line in file:
        val = line.split(":")
        if len(val) == 2  and val[0].strip() == what:
            return val[1].strip()
    return ""

# это имитация чтения из файла
from io import StringIO

file = StringIO("""123:4000
567:3000
890:2000""")


#val = search(open("test.txt"), "567")
val = search(file, "567")
print(val) # "3000"
```

Вариант с регулярными выражениями:

```
>>> import re
>>> def search(s, what):
    m = re.search(fr"(?:{what}):(\d+)", s)
    if m: return m.group(1)
    return ""

>>> s = StringIO("""123:4000
567:3000
890:2000""").read()  # это как если бы мы прочитали файл
>>> search(s, "567")
'3000'
>>> search(s, "890")
'2000'
>>> search(s, "1000")
''
```

Comment: Ого... Зачем так много?

Comment: Но круто. За это плюсик.

Comment: :) Экзотика есть

Answer (score 0):

Простой код в лоб (*удобная структура данных в данном случае - словарь*):

```
sl={}
t=open('file.txt')
tr=t.read()
tr = tr.split('\n')
for i in tr: sl[int(i.split(':')[0])] = int(i.split(':')[1])
per = (sl[int(input('Поиск: '))])
print(per)
```

**Ввод:**

```
Поиск: 567
```

**Вывод:**

```
3000
```

Comment: Зачем в int переводить каждый раз?

Comment: Ахах, только щас увидел текст. Ты клоун, вхвхвх

Comment: @IvanZ что? что такое?

Answer (score 0):

Простой код

```
f = open('file.txt', 'r')
sl = {}
for pairs in f:
  sl[pairs.split(':')[0]] = pairs.split(':')[1]
number = sl[input()]
print(number)
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132533/discussion-on-answer-by-ivanz--------).

Answer (score 0):

С помощью регулярки:

```
from re import search

k = '890'
with open('file.txt') as f:
    res = s[1] if (s := search(fr'{k}:(\d+)', f.read())) else 'не найдено'
    
print(res)  # '2000'
```